# Wildfly 10 - read configuration parameter programmatically

Tags: undertow, wildfly-10

I have this in my standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
       <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" max-post-size="10000000" ...
```

Is there a way to read the value of `max-post-size` programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Start by having a look at the [Management API reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Management+API+reference) documentation. That will give you an overview of management model.

You can read the attribute with the [HTTP API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/The+HTTP+management+API), [CLI scripting](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AdvancedCLIScriptingWithGroovyRhinoJythonEtc), or using the [native management client](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/The+native+management+API). Below is an example using the native management client.

```java
try (final ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9990)) {
    final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("subsystem", "undertow", "server", "default-server", "http-listener", "default");
    final ModelNode op = Operations.createReadAttributeOperation(address, "max-post-size");
    final ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
    if (Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
        System.out.println(Operations.readResult(result).asLong());
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
    }
}
```

If you're using maven you'd just need a dependency on `org.wildfly.core:wildfly-controller-client:2.2.0.Final`. There's also a `jboss-client.jar` in the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/client` directory that can be placed on the class path which will have all the required binaries.